# Get only last chat message of whole friend list of a user from database

Tags: php, sql

I need a query in sql which can get me the details of the last message of all the friends of the user .The fields in my sql database are :

```
message_id      (primary key)
sender          (username of the sender)
message_content (text of the message)
user_id         (user id of the app user)
friend_id       (user id of the app user's friends)
message_time    (time of the message receive on server)
receiver        (user id of the receiver)
```

**Edit** : So far I think my closest try was

```
Select * from user_chat_messages where message_id on (Select distinct message_id from user_chat_messages order by message_time limit 1,0);
```

Rest all other queries that I tried were a total failure  :(

Comment: which sql database is that?

Comment: Actually I am not a php developer and I tried everything possible I could do.I know about normal select queries but I think it needs nested query  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common mysql problem where you need to join a table on itself to get a result set with the min / max of each unique user.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1 
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(message_time) AS 'time', friend_id, user_id 
  FROM table GROUP BY friend_id, user_id
) t2 ON (t1.message_time = t2.time AND t1.friend_id = t2.friend_id AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id)
```

Essentially your subquery finds the latest time grouped by friend_id and then joins it back to the main table so that it only pulls the record with the latest time from the first table. From there you can add a WHERE statement to only show the latest messages from a specific user - adding the condition in the subquery will actually improve the performance

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1 
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(message_time) AS 'time', friend_id, user_id 
  FROM table 
  WHERE user_id=? GROUP BY friend_id
) t2 ON (t1.message_time = t2.time AND t1.friend_id = t2.friend_id  AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying.I am checking it now.

Comment: Sorry I think I asked a bit incorrectly.Your query is working good but its only sending me my own sent last message in response.I also need to retrieve the message of my friend sent to me.

Comment: I changed the code in my ios app to make it work with your query  :D
Thanks a lot for the help  ^_^

Comment: @PradeepMittal if we want all users last chat, we have to keep this query in loop?